# How to do authentication onedrive for Business and upload a file (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, oauth, office365

Im trying to make a app which uploads the files with the C# code I write to Microsoft Office 365 OneDrive for Business.
I tried several things to get the refresh token and access token.
But I could not find the way how to implement this on the web.

I tried to use [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx) blog explenation on how to authenticate with REST.
This is what I have got so far:

```
private void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(GetAuthorizationUrl());
}

private string GetAuthorizationUrl()
{
    // Create a request for an authorization code.
    string url = string.Format("    {0}common/oauth2/authorize?&response_type=code&client_id={1}&resource={2}&redirect_uri={3}&state={4}",
        _authorizationEndpoint,
        _clientId,
        _resource,
        _redirectURI,
        _state);
    return url;
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("code="))
    {
        var splited = e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split(new char[] { '=', '&' });
        _authorizationInformation.Code = splited[1];
        _authorizationInformation.SessionState = splited[3];

        if (_authorizationInformation.SessionState.Equals(_state))
        {
            GetTokenInformation(_authorizationInformation);
        }
    }
}
    
private TokenInformation GetTokenInformation(AuthorizationInformation authInformation)
{
    try
    {
        var response = Post(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_tokenEndpoint), new NameValueCollection(){ 
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
            { "code", authInformation.Code },
            { "redirect_uri", _redirectURI },
            { "client_id", _clientId },
            { "client_secret", _clientSecret },
        });

        Stream responseStream = new MemoryStream(response);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            _tokenInformation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenInformation>(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error" + exception.HResult.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the method GetTokenInformation the response is always empty 0 bytes. 
**First question: How do I correctly authenticate with OAuth to onedrive pro?**
**Second question: When I got the accesstoken how do I upload a file?**

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can not use OAuth authentication for SharePoint online in Windows client applications(including Windows Form applications).  This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470%28v=office.15%29.aspx) shows the OAuth flow for  SharePoint online: you need a server URL as the app’s registered redirect URI, but Windows Forms application doesn't have that.

Another way to do it is to use [SharePoint client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fp179912.aspx), the code below shows how to access the OneDrive:

```
        string username = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
        String pwd = "xxx#";
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx_xxxinc_onmicrosoft_com/");

        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray())
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);            }

        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
        //login in to SharePoint online
        context.ExecuteQuery();   

        //OneDrive is acctually a Document list
        List docs = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
        ListItemCollection items = docs.GetItems(query);

        // Retrieve all items the document list
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem["Title"]);
        }
```

Also, you can use REST Apis, this article [Access OneDrive for Business using the SharePoint 2013 APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/08/13/access-skydrive-pro-using-the-sharepoint-2013-apis.aspx) explains how to use REST to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I finally got a connection with my OneDrive. Altough I have to log in each time I want access. Is there a way to get a refresh token after a log in? So the next time the user uses my application, I can use that refresh token to get a accesstoken in order to excecute commands with CMOS to OneDrive.

Comment: @Castrovalva, according to my knowledge, there's no such token for Windows client application, if asp.net, you can do it.